# Rails and coffeescript popup only working on first object in array

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I have a products page listing several different products. When a products main image is clicked i would like a popup/lightbox to display with another image of that product and additional information.

However, the click event is only working for the first product:

```
$(document).ready ->
 i = $(".main-image").attr("data-productid")
 button = $("#single_" + i)
 button.on "click", ->
  $("#product_popup").show()
```

The html/erb:

```
<% products.each do |product| %>
<% if product.on_display? %>
  <div class="grid_1">
  <li id="product_<%= product.id %>" class="columns product three <%= cycle("alpha", "secondary", "", "omega secondary", :name => "classes") %>" data-hook="products_list_item" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
    <div class="main-image" id="single_<%= product.id %>" data-productid="<%= product.id %>">
      <%= large_image(product, :itemprop => "image", :class => "product-image", :id => product.id) %>
    </div><!-- main-image-->
    <%# ******LIGHTBOX******* %>
    <div id="product_popup">
        <%= large_image(product, :itemprop => "image", :class => "product-image") %>
    </div><!-- product_popup -->
```

Thanks for any help. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
jQuery ->
  $(".main-image").each () ->
    i = $(this).attr("data-productid")
    $("#single_" + i).on "click", ->
      $("#product_popup").show()
```

You need to call each on you .main-image selector, so the code inside each is executed to each of your div.main-image. notice the $(this) inside the each, that will be relative to each of your div during each iteration of the each loop.

I thing you can refactor like this (try the solution above first to confirm it's working)

```
jQuery ->
  $("div.main-image").on "click", ->
    $("div#product_popup").show()
```

Comment: That definitely got me one step closer. Now all of the products are clickable and bring up the product-popup div, but every product, when clicked on, displays the first product image, not the image of the product that was clicked on. Any ideas? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes, if you use the first piece of code in my answer, replace `$("#product_popup").show()` by `$("li#product_" + i + " #product_popup").show()`

Comment: Tried that, and it works for the first product, but when I click on the other products nothing happened. This is my coffeescript:

`jQuery ->
  $(".main-image").each () ->
    i = $(this).attr("data-productid")
    $("#single_" + i).on "click", ->
      $("li#product_" + i + " #product_popup").show()`

Comment: hey jtrinker, don't forget to reward answers, that's the way it works here

Comment: I was waiting for a response. I figured it out though.